# Is it possible to customise laravel eloquent morphToMany's name_type column?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

We can customise `morphMany` `$type`

**morphMany**

```
public function morphMany($related, $name, $type = null, $id = null, $localKey = null)
```

By using official doc example. I can change `commentable_type` to `commentable_object` in database schema by passing the third parameter `$type` with `commentable_object`

```
comments
id - integer
body - text
commentable_id - integer
commentable_type - string
```

However, `morphToMany` function has no this this parameter.

Here is the source code of morphToMany

```php
public function __construct(Builder $query, Model $parent, $name, $table, $foreignPivotKey, $relatedPivotKey, $parentKey, $relatedKey, $relationName = null, $inverse = false)
{
    $this->inverse = $inverse;
    $this->morphType = $name.'_type';
    $this->morphClass = $inverse ? $query->getModel()->getMorphClass() : $parent->getMorphClass();
    parent::__construct(
        $query, $parent, $table, $foreignPivotKey,
        $relatedPivotKey, $parentKey, $relatedKey, $relationName
    );
}
```

It always use

```php
$this->morphType = $name.'_type';
```

to create `morphType`. Why `morphToMany` does not allow to change the name of `$type` column?

Answer (score 3):

It is not currently possible. [A similar question was asked](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/25440) in the [Laravel github issues](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues), with the conclusion being that it cannot be customised.

If you would like to see this changed in a future Laravel release, I recommend that you submit an issue on the [Laravel Ideas](https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues) repo.

Alternatively, you could fork the Laravel repo and customise the source code to suit your needs.